# LQR for inverted pendulum

Tags: control-system, automation

I'm studying an optimal control for the inverted pendulum in the following figure

[image]

the state and the output of the system are defined as
$$x=\begin{bmatrix}r & \theta & \dot{r} & \dot{\theta} \end{bmatrix}^T, \quad y=\begin{bmatrix}r & \theta-\alpha & \dot{r} \end{bmatrix}^T$$

so the continuos state space model at the upright equilibrium is
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}(t)&=Ax(t)+B_u u(t)+B_\alpha \alpha(t)+B_\tau \tau(t)+B_{F_s}F_s\text{sign}(\dot{r}(t)) \\
y(t)&=Cx(t)+D_\alpha\alpha(t)
\end{cases}
where the disturbance inclination \$\alpha\$ is suppose costant, \$\tau\$ is a torque disturbance, \$B_{F_s}F_s\text{sign}(\dot{r}(t))\$ is a Coulomb's friction term and \$u\$ is the input force applied to the cart. The numerical values for the transfer matrices are
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 2.8040 & -5.2658 & 0 \\ 0 & 18.5885 & -19.6959 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad B_u=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 3.7629 \\ 5.5257 \end{bmatrix}, \quad B_\alpha=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ -12.6447 \\ 18.5885 \end{bmatrix}, \quad B_\tau=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0.5650 \\ 3.7629 \end{bmatrix}, \quad B_{F_s}=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ -1.1187 \\ -0.5650\end{bmatrix}  $$
$$C=\begin{bmatrix} I_3 & 0_{3\times1}\end{bmatrix} ,\qquad D_\alpha=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$$
where \$I_n\$ is the identity matrix \$n\times n\$ and \$0_{m\times n}\$ is the null matrix \$m\times n\$.

For a digital implementation is required a suitable sampling of the previus system, so the discrete relative state-space model is in the form
\begin{cases}
x_{k+1}&=\Phi x_k+\Gamma_u u_k+\Gamma_\alpha \alpha_k+\Gamma_\tau \tau_k+N_k(\dot{r}_k) \\
y_k&=Cx_k+D_\alpha\alpha_k
\end{cases}

Now there is my problem. To counteract the effects of constant rail inclinations a discrete-time integrator is appended to the model \$(\Phi,\Gamma_u)\$. Is taked in the simple form
\begin{equation}\tag{1} w_{k+1}=w_k+r_k\end{equation}
so the extended state of the system become
$$x^{\text{e}}=\begin{bmatrix}x & w\end{bmatrix}^T$$
and the state feedback is designed by minimization of the cost function
$$J(u)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (x_k^\text{e})^TQx_k^\text{e}+Ru_k^2$$
where the cost's matrices \$Q\$ must be semi-defined positive and the scalar cost \$R\$ must be strictly positive.

I can't understand the function of the integrator \$(1)\$. The rail inclination affect both input and output of the system, so the integral action counteracts only the effect on output. Moreover, the state matrix \$A\$ is singular, so the system at least has one integral action by itself, and no more integrators has to appended to the system.

Maybe the integrator \$(1)\$ is considered for drive the position of the cart to the start of the rail, i.e. \$r=0\$.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: The steady state position error with a integrator is zero in response to a step input . Classic PID loop thesis topic.

Comment: So is wrong to say *"To counteract the effects of constant rail inclinations a discrete-time integrator is appended to the model \$(\Phi, \Gamma_u)\$"*? 
And another thing: is really necessary take an integrator to reject the stady state position error? I mean, the LQR, also without the integrator, will drive the state of the system to the origin, then \$r=0\$

Comment: If the parameters in \$A\$, etc change then the actual \$\dot{r}\$ after implementation will not be zero. The cart could end up sliding in one direction. The integral of \$r\$ will cause the cart to move back and forth and eventually settle down.

Comment: I'm not sure how you choose your variables but for PID control systems we know the steady state error in response to a  ramp input, step, impulse quadratic etc.  The I or integrator smoothens, filters and amplifies accumulated error for feedback.  Does the continuous LQG/LQR  do similar?

Comment: As you can see, the cost function is defined on an infinite horizon of control, then, necessarily, the series converge if the state is null from a certain sampling instant \$k_f\$, i.e. 
$$x_k=0 \quad \forall k\ge k_f$$ 
It follow that the LQR guarantees a null steady state error, like a PI controller.

However I believe that i figured out the problem. The integral action, in respect to the disturbance \$\alpha\$, is positioned in the return branch of the feedback ring, so, for the internal model principle, the state feedback will reject the effect of \$\alpha\$.